# Animation not run second time in responsive view when scroll down the page and up

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with a jQuery issue for an animation not run second time in a responsive view when we move the page down and up. Below is the jQuery code. [Here](http://testurproject.tk/deveod/EOD-New/home-sme.html) is the link

```js
var btn_ffLife = !1;
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

$("#flip").click(function() {
  alert(btn_ffLife);
  if (!btn_ffLife) {
    alert(btn_ffLife);
    $(".free-for-life img").animate({
      'right': "200px"
    });
    $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
    btn_ffLife = !0
  } else {
    $(".free-for-life img").animate({
      'right': "-50px"
    });
    $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
    btn_ffLife = !1
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  btn_ffLife = !1;
  if (scroll >= 375) {
    $("body").addClass("darkHeader");
    $("#panel").css('display', 'none');
    $(".free-for-life img").animate({
      'left': "50px"
    })
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("darkHeader");
    $("#panel").css('display', 'block');
    $(".free-for-life img").animate({
      'left': "50px"
    })
  }
  if (windowWidth < 1182) {
    $("#panel").css('display', 'none')
  }
});
```

Comment: Which animation is not working?

Comment: Try Now yellow button. In responsive view,  when I clicked the toggle navigation, the button should move towards left and vice versa. I also want that when we scroll down it hides the open panel of navigation and when I comes up,  scroll up,  try now button again start same effect on click of toggle navigation.

Comment: I am talking about web version not mobile version.